# Foundation 5 Top bar not working on Android browser

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

The http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html example page works for every kind of browser, in "small" resolution range, except one: Android's stock (default) browser.

While using Chrome, Firefox, Safari (and even IE) you can drill down all our 5 levels.

Android browser works well with the first 2 levels of the dropdown menu, but **does not display the third level at all** !

At first I thought it was my menu, but the official docs/demo page breaks too!

I think it is a bug, but cannot find it in the bug tracker.

*NB*:: Same behavior in every version (2 to 4.3) and device.

Comment: I had this same problem, and found in a foundation forum the official response was that you should not be using more than 2 levels of depth. I disagree, the developer decides and the framework should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me this works to fix the issue on stock Android Browsers

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .top-bar.expanded .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.moved > .dropdown { clip:initial;}
    .top-bar.expanded .top-bar-section .dropdown {clip:initial;}
}
```

Not tested on iOS Devices maybe someone can test it on iOS Browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my example top-bar, http://cdpn.io/cBjun, to work five levels deep on my phone running Android 4.3. After creating the example I would suggest you double checking the following:

- Your meta viewport is set correctly, such as:

  - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`
- You have valid HTML with the correct nesting of `ul`, `li`, and `a`; which you can check using the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/). Remember that once you open an `ul` and `li` you do not close them again until you have completed the menu item. If you look at my example the last thirteen or so lines are just closing tags.
- You have the correct CSS classes with `<li class="has-dropdown">` on the menu item you want to have the dropdown and `<ul class="dropdown">` nested within the `li` after the `a` to create the dropdown.

If you have any questions let me know, and a link to the site or your top-bar code would help the community, help you, diagnose the issue.

I hope that helps.

*EDIT 03/27/2014*

I checked my codepen on my phone and took the following screen shot:

[image: codepen on Galaxy S4]

Also note that my example was created in version 5.2.1.

Comment: just tested it, both via https://saucelabs.com and with a real device with 4.3.... clicking 'level 1' dropdown doesn't work: it actually closes the topbar! Sorry and thank you however...